# Multiple OL views for single OL Map instance

Tags: openlayers, sql-view

I need to show multiple views of the same OpenLayer Map instance. Each view would have a different extent, but display the same layers visible on the Map instance. Is that possible? It's important to share the Map state between both views, so I don't believe creating separate Map instances is viable.

Comment: You can move views between maps, or share them between two or more maps.  The center, resolution and rotation are shared between the maps, but the maps could have different sizes. 
https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/teleport.html 
https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/side-by-side.html 

You can also change the view in single map - in this case as the center moves a new view is created based on the local UTM projection
https://jsfiddle.net/9v308d65/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm looking for the opposite--having multiple views with different extents (aka center and zoom) of the same map.

Comment: Yes, that's easy, just call `map.setView()`  If you have already used a view the state you left it in is remembered https://jsfiddle.net/xgnqjhrc/

Comment: Ah, yeah, but at the same time. One high level view of the map, and a few other detail views of the same map.

Comment: A map can only use one view at any time,  A map can have a overview map (via the OverviewMap control, but that is like having two maps.

Answer (score 0):

It can be brought easly by invoking below API as much as time you needed.

**Note:** target should be different.

```
var map = new Map({
view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  }),
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map'
});
```

See the below image which creates more than one map instance in a single page.

[image]

Comment: I was thinking multiple views for the same map instance, not multiple maps each with its own map instance. That way I could define the map instance once, but then have multiple ways to view it on the page.

Comment: Then you might be pointing to Shared view. Please check the below link. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/side-by-side.html

Comment: In reverse: one map with multiple views. I want a single map instance, but display multiple areas zoomed in, like your example above (except your example creates multiple map instances).

Comment: I don't think it is possible as the view is purely depends on the map object. 
I tried to call the create map function with target as same div id. 
But the result was no positive.